# code for drawing a line from start point to goal point not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a simple python code for navigating a map. 
After traversing the map, I find the start point and end point.
I then want to draw a line from start point to end point.

code for navigation:

```
mymap2 = generateMap((20,20))
print mymap2

def find_start_goal():

    for i in range(20):
        for j in range(20):
            if mymap2[[i],[j]] == -3:
                print ("goal point Located Pos: [%d,%d]" % (j,i) )
                goal1 = [j,i]
            elif mymap2[[i],[j]] == -2:
                print ("Star point Located Pos: [%d,%d]" % (j,i) )
                start1 = [j,i]
            else:
                pass

    return start1 , goal1

start1 , goal1 = find_start_goal()

print "start = ", start1
print "goal = ", goal1
path = [start1,goal1]


plotMap(mymap2,path)
```

The code in the `plotMap` function that plots the line:

```
plt.plot(path_[:][0], path_[:][1], color='red', linewidth=2.5)
```

The problem is that `plt.plot` expects as its first two arguments the variables `X` and `Y`, where `X` should be a tuple: (`x` from start point , `x` from goal point) and similarly for the end point of the line.

and hence the line is never from start point to goal point.

So what is the problem in the `plt.plot(pat_...)`?

I am using numpy and matplotlib.

Comment: Your map is i,j but your point is j,i. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes i have adjusted it as per the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `plotMap`, write:

```
path_ = zip(*path_)
```

just before your plotting line (although I guess there are a few better places to do this in your code, but without seeing it, we cannot make recommendations on that).

This will give you the x-coordinates of begin and end point in the first element of `path_` and the y-coordinate in the second element, just like `plt.plot` expects:

Example:

```
>>> begin = [0,0]
>>> end = [10,5]
>>> path = [begin, end]
>>> zip(*path)
[(0, 10), (0, 5)]
```